# Evaluate $\oint_C |z|^2 dz$ around the square with vertices at $(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1)$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

I don't think I quite understand how to go about this.

My solution so far:

$\oint_C |z|^2 dz = \oint_C (x^2 + y^2)dz = \oint_C (x^2 + y^2) d(x+iy) = \oint_C x^2 + y^2 dx + i\oint_Cx^2+y^2dy$.

Then, I just plug in $(0,0) \to (1,0), (1,0) \to (1,1), (1,1) \to (0,1), (0,1) \to (0,0)$.

For $(0,0) \to (1,0)$, I get $\frac{1}{3}$
For $(1,0) \to (1,1)$, I get $1 + i\frac{4}{3}$
For $(1,1) \to (0,1)$, I get $-\frac{4}{3} - i$
For $(0,1) \to (0,0)$, I get $-i\frac{1}{3}$

When all is said and done, I get $0$, but apparently the answer is $-1+i$. I'm not sure where I went wrong, or if I just don't understand what I'm doing.

Comment: Could you tell us what answer you got for each segment?

Comment: @KieranCooney, is my logic correct? I will edit the question to answer your question.

Comment: 2nd step: $(1,0) \to (1,1)$ we have $dx=0$ and $x=1$ so the integral is $i\int_0^1 1+y^2 \, \mathrm{d}y=\frac{4i}{3}$, how did you get your $1$ there? Similarly, the 3rd step has $x=y=1$ and $dy=0$ so the integral is $\int_1^0 2 \, \mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm having a hard time understanding complex integration. I suppose because x didn't change at all, dx is zero, and wherever I see an x I substitute it with 1. Is that correct, @BoSchmidt

Comment: Exactly! Because on the line segment $(1,0)$ to $(1,1)$, $x$ simply has the value $1$ and doesn't change.

Comment: So, for step 2: I have (1,0) to (1,1), then x = 1, and dx is zero. I will maintain y as a variable but all x become 1. However, you said for step 3: x = y = 1. I understand why dy = 0, but x goes from 1 to 0 in (1,1) to (0,1), so why did you say x = y = 1, and not y = 1?

Comment: Of course only $y=1$ in the 3rd step, should be edited! Gotta have the variable in there. The integral becomes $\int_1^0 1+x^2 \, \mathrm{d}x$

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought :). Let me compute this, and I'll update this with my result.

Comment: I got $-1 + i$. Thanks a ton, @BoSchmidt

Comment: Well done ;) And you're welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're kind of missing the point with your treatment of the contour integral.  All you need to do is evaluate separately on each side.  To do so, you need to parametrize.  Let the sides of the square be $C_1$, $C_2$, C_3$, and $C_4$, where these sides are defined as follows:

$$C_1 = \{z : z=x , x\in [0,1] \}$$
$$C_2 = \{z : z=1+i y , y\in [0,1] \}$$
$$C_3 = \{z : z=x+i , x\in [1,0] \}$$
$$C_4 = \{z : z=i y , y\in [1,0] \}$$

so that

$$\oint_C dz \, |z|^2 = \int_0^1 dx \, x^2 + i \int_0^1 dy (1+y^2) + \int_1^0 dx (1+x^2) + i \int_1^0 dy \, y^2$$

Note that the integrals over $x^2$ and $y^2$ cancel, but we are left with

$$\oint_C dz \, |z|^2 = -1+i$$

Answer (score 1):

Another (slightly fancier) way to do this computation is with Green's theorem in complex coordinates. Letting $S$ be the square, and using $|z|^2 = z\bar{z}$

$$\begin{align*}
\int_{C} |z|^2 dz &= \int_S d(z\bar{z}dz)\\
&= \int_S (zd\bar{z}+\bar{z}dz) \wedge dz\\
&=\int_S zd\bar{z}\wedge dz\\
\end{align*}$$

now $d\bar{z}\wedge dz = (dx -idy)\wedge (dx+idy) = 2idx\wedge dy$, so we get

$$\begin{align*}
\hphantom{\int_{C} |z|^2 dz fdgfd}&=2i\int_S (x+iy)dxdy\\
&=2i\int_S x dxdy - 2\int y dxdy
\end{align*}$$

Each of these real double integrals can be easily evaluated to be $\frac{1}{2}$, so we get $i-1$, confirming the "right answer" you were given.

Just offering another perspective, and hopefully an advertisement to learn something about complex differential forms :)

Answer (score 0):

"For (1,1)→(0,1), I get −4/3 −i"

The fault lies here.

You should get - 4/3 only, as y remains same and dy=0

Which gives the answer - 1 +i

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).